# How to pass a checkbox id from HTML to JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am attempting to write a Jquery function that moves any selected checkboxes from one div to another. However, I'm not sure how to pass the page id for each checkbox from the HTML template code to JQuery. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<fieldset>   
    <h3>Pages</h3>
    <div class="fieldset_elements">
        <div id="pagecontainer">
            <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox1">
                <h4>Available Pages</h4>
                    {foreach from=$pagelist item=page}
                         <div class="pageSelection">
                             <input type="checkbox" id="{$page.id}"
                                    value="{$page.id}"
                                    {if $page.id eq $selectedPage}
                                    selected="true"
                                    {/if}" />
                             {$page.page_name}
                         </div>
                    {/foreach}
            </div>
            <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox2">
                <h4>Selected Pages</h4>
                {foreach from=$selectedPage item=page}
                    <span id="page" class="pageSelection"> 
                        <option value="{$page.id}"
                            {if $page.id eq $selectedPage}
                                selected="true"
                            {/if}">
                          {$page.page_name}
                        </option>
                    </span>
                {/foreach}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

```js
$(function () {
    // Check if user clicks on the checkbox
    $('#' + id).click(function() {

        if($('#' + id).is(":checked")){

            $("#pagebox1").contents().appendTo("#pagebox2");
        } else {

            $("#pagebox2").contents().appendTo("#pagebox1");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use the `this` keyword to reference the element within a click handler: `if ($(this).is(":checked"))...` or more simply: `if (this.checked)...`

Comment: Would this be the same for  $('#' + id).click(function()..? I.e.  $(this).click(function() {...?

Comment: No, as that does not have the required scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click as an event handler, this will make this a lot simpler. You can get (and set) the value HTML-attributes (id’s are also attributes) with the [`attr()`-method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). In your example you would get the value of `id="{$page.id}"` with:

```
$('.pagecontainer input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    var pageId = $(this).attr('id'); //pageId now contains the id

    // ... your code with small adjustments
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass an id like you're doing just now..

You can target all the input elements as a one using `$("#pagebox1 > input[type='checkbox']")`

Full code

```
$("#pagebox1 > input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
    //checked
  }
})
```

```js
var elements = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6"];

$.each(elements, function(idx, item){
 $("#pagebox1").append(`<input type='checkbox' id='Test_${idx}'>${item}</input>`);
});


// Start of answer

$("#pagebox1 > input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
   alert("Checked");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox1">

</div>
```